# Mac Pro 2019 Absolutely Will Not Boot!

Tags: macos, recovery, mac-pro, ventura

So to set the scene, I have a 250GB SSD and a 2TB SSD in my Mac Pro 2019. I wasn't using the 2TB SSD, so OS and files were all on 250GB which filled up rather rapidly, so I decided to use the 2TB drive for files only. I decided to try move my home folder to the 2TB SSD via the system settings...bad idea...dead OS.

So then I did <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to get into recovery mode and erased the OS drive. For some reason I couldn't get the 2TB drive to mount, so I restarted...

That went from bad to worse!...now I have that flashing folder icon.

I've tried:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wireless)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wired)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (different keyboard)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wireless)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wired)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (different keyboard)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wireless)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wired)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (different keyboard)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wireless)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (wired)
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (different keyboard)
- Booting from a Ventura Bootable USB...still nothing.

What on Earth do I do now?

Comment: Are you saying that Command R doesn't actually boot to Recovery anymore? Did you erase the ENTIRE SSD, rather than just the Data volume?

Comment: What are the results of each of your tests? Unless you enabled boot from external devices, you're probably also stuck on this - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198

Comment: @benwiggy Possibly the entire SSD. There was a recovery volume as well, but that appeared in the disk utility as a separate volume, so my assumption was that this was separate to the SSD itself (i.e. something built into the firmware, although I have not investigated this in depth)

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't even get into the recovery console to be able to see what options are/aren't available, however I'm pretty sure that before this started, external boot was enabled. For reference, I've been able to boot and recover from USB before on this machine.

Comment: “Recovery console”?  When you boot Internet Recovery (4th-9th key combo in your question), you should download a minimal version of macOS GUI specifically for installation tasks.  What are you seeing?  It’s not clear from comments or the question.

Comment: @Allan even that key combo wasn’t working - none of them were. Every combo just resulted in the flashing question mark folder icon.

Comment: Are you pressing and holding them at boot time?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you erased the entire SSD, then you will have deleted the Recovery Partition, and the Preboot volume.
*"Don't do this."*

Modern Macs also have security settings that prohibit booting from external volumes by default.
https://support.apple.com/HT208198

It's unlikely that moving the home folder would cause a 'dead' OS. At worst, it would boot into a brand new user account.

If you don't have a second Mac, which you can connect to the Mac Pro and run [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12) on, then you'll have to take it to an Apple Store or other authorised Apple repair shop.

They will also be able to determine whether there's an underlying fault that caused the dead OS.

Comment: I do have a second Mac, and am installing Apple Configurator on it. Are there any instructions online as to how I should use it to recover a dead machine?

Comment: @MatthewLayton Try this: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-configurator-mac/apdebea5be51/mac